# if Delegate sends gesture messages do they conform to my customised Objective C protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to send gesture messages from several subclassed `UIViews` to common handlers in a `UIViewController` called `TouchController.` I am using a customised protocol to address a question arising from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49246628/2348597) to my [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49246176/2348597).

Messages are now sent from `OneOfSeveralSubviews` using a customised protocol called `FirstGestureRecognizerDelegate` but none of the handlers respond even though the code compiles with 0 warnings. I am confident the problem is not in `TouchController` for reasons [stated previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49246176/2348597). And after looking at more references (*below*) and checking out possible duplicates (*below*) I am now looking for answers to a new set of questions.

---

See Note (below) for my response to a possible duplicate question.

---

Here is my customised protocol

**OneOfSeveralSubviews.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol FirstGestureRecognizerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer;
- (void)handleTapSelect:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer;
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer;

@end

@interface OneOfSeveralSubviews : UIView
{
    CGRect touchFrame;
}

- (id)initView:(CGRect)rect;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<FirstGestureRecognizerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In the implementation of `OneOfSeveralSubviews,` gestures are defined by declaring instances of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and setting their delegate properties

e.g.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGR = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(id)self.delegate 
                                                                                          action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
[longPressGR setDelegate:(id)self.delegate];
```

The program runs but is unresponsive. I’m not sure if this happens because it [a] *sends* messages that conform to a protocol the handlers ignore OR [b] *can’t find a way to send* messages that conform to a protocol the handlers recognise. References I’ve looked at give no clue whether it is [a] or [b]. Moreover [this document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/implementing_a_custom_gesture_recognizer?language=objc) uses the term subclassing to mean something different to subclassing in my situation and the illustrated code examples are in Swift rather than Objective C.

This leads me to ask:

1. can `UILongPressGestureRecognizer,` `UITapGestureRecognizer` and
   `UIPanGestureRecognizer` actually be used with my customised
   protocol ?
2. or does a customised protocol also require customised gesture
   recognition methods rather than standard methods (i.e. pre-fixed
   with `UI`) ?
3. either way, are there simple code changes that would let the
   delegate send gesture messages that conform to the customised
   protocol ? or
4. is it possible I’m trying to do something that is conceptually flawed ?

I’d welcome answers to these questions or a better question if there is one.

**OneOfSeveralSubviews.m**

```
#import "OneOfSeveralSubviews.h"

@implementation OneOfSeveralSubviews

- (id)initView:(CGRect)rect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:rect];
    if (self)
    {
        // Set view size and color

        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGR = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(id)self.delegate action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
        [longPressGR setDelegate:(id)self.delegate];
        [longPressGR setMinimumPressDuration:0.6f];
        [longPressGR setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [longPressGR setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
        [hotspot addGestureRecognizer:longPressGR];

        // Create and configure two other gesture recognizers

        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**TouchController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "OneOfSeveralSubviews.h"
#import "TwoOfSeveralSubviews.h"

// #import "ThreeOfSeveralSubviews.h"
// #import "FourOfSeveralSubviews.h"
//          etc.

@interface TouchController : UIViewController <FirstGestureRecognizerDelegate, SecondGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    CGRect touchFrame;
    CGRect screenFrame;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;

@end
```

**TouchController.m**

```
#import "TouchController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation TouchController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    OneOfSeveralSubviews *oneForAll=[[OneOfSeveralSubviews alloc] initView:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:oneForAll];    
}
```

I've looked through these related posts:

- [Implementing a Custom Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/implementing_a_custom_gesture_recognizer?language=objc)
- [UIGestureRecognizers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer?language=objc)
- [Working with protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW1)
- [Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH10-SW1)
- [Avoid category method name clashes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4)
- [Customizing Existing Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW1)
- [Handling app delegates and switching between views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948727/2348597)
- [differences between weak and assign property?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12861256/2348597)

**NOTE**

I checked [Scott’s duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10315800/2348597) and it is definitely asking a question similar to those being asked here. But in Scott’s example it also looks as if delegation that originates *inside* the `ViewController` is destined for a target outside the `Viewcontroller` (i.e. in `MakePlantTVC`). Whereas in my case, delegation that originates *outside* the `ViewController` is destined for a target *inside* the `ViewController.` For that reason I would never have picked Scott’s question as a duplicate even though to a more experienced person such a difference might seem insignificant.

These possible duplicates are very similar but don't solve my problem:

- [Declare that delegate conforms to another protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28824248/2348597)
- [How to conditionally conform to delegate protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31597456/2348597)
- [UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33605700/2348597)

Comment: You don't seem to ever create an object to act as the delegate.

Comment: one quick point, have you considered moving to Swift?  it is incredibly better (and easier as a bonus)

Comment: Other than that, what you're doing is totally fine. And good research!

Comment: I don’t understand your comment but I suspect you could be saying what Paul was trying to tell me here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49246628/2348597

Comment: I guess I needn’t  worry about q.4. BTW, a neat edit! (I never know what to leave out). I missed this duplicate. I’m checking it out. Thanks on all counts.

Comment: Fattie, I can't wait to move to Swift. I need to tie this up app that began with iOS4

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I've worked out my response to the duplicate question. See my edit.

Comment: You're missing the tree for the forest. This "inside"/"outside" distinction has no relevance. You _haven't created a delegate_. Nothing happens because nothing is there to make it happen. When you say `initWithTarget:(id)self.delegate`, `self.delegate` is `nil`.

Comment: This shouldn't have been reopened. [The answer at the dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315800/why-is-this-delegate-protocol-not-responding) says this, very first thing: _"Have you set the delegate? It might sound stupid but when a delegate doesn't work it's because I forget..."_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167001/discussion-between-greg-and-josh-caswell).